# Best technology to compare 2 large sets of data

Tags: database, performance, comparison

## Problem

Every day we recieve a new set of data files from our backoffice application. This application is not able to produce an incremental changeset so all it can do is dump to a large file.

Currently every morning we drop our old MySQL tables and load the data into uor database.

One of the problems we have here is that we are unable to act on specific changes in the data and also we are using CQRS and would have quite some benefits here if we had an incremental list.

- File format is currently CSV
- Data size per file is up to 10GB
- Number of rows per file is up to 40 million
- Approximately 30 data files
- On average less than 1% of rows is changed each day
- Most files either have no primary key or a combined primary key. For many, the full row is the only thing that makes them unique.
- The order of data is not fixed. Rows may switch positions

## Desired situation

When we receive the new data we calculate the difference and push a message into Kafka for each changed (if a rowidentifier exists), added or removed row.

## Technology

- We use AWS and are able to use all technologies AWS offers
- We are not limited to a certain amount of hardware. We can just start up some new servers in AWS
- Cost is only a very limited factor. We have quite a large budget and the ability to have an incremental set offers us quite a lot of value.
- We have a running Kubernetes cluster

## Question

So the main question is, What would be the best way to compare these 2 large files and create an incremental set? We need it to be fast, preferably within the hour or close to that.

Are there database types that have this natively or are there technologies that can do this for us?

Answer (score 1):

"...The order of data is not fixed. Rows may switch positions..." That is the one that makes it hard. If the rows did not change a `git diff` or text file comparison tool would work.

[Spitballing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/were-just-spitballing-here) here but:

1. For each row create a SHA hash
2. Use the hash as a unique ID
3. Store each UNIQUE hash and associated data into a DB Table.
4. Post processing the file, dump the table into a text file (CSV/SQL/etc)
5. Commit file changes to source control
6. When you receive a new data set, check if the hash exists

   - If no: append the hash to the end of the table
   - If yes: ignore
7. Dump the table into a text file (CSV/SQL/etc)
8. 'git diff' commits to see change sets.

Might be able to do this with [AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/)...

Bonus:
To make it even easier create a location the back office app can upload the file and create a cron to process the report at a given time

This process is a typical [ETL (Extract-Transform-Load)](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/E/ETL.html) task. You are extracting data from one source/format, changing it, and loading/inserting it into a different source/format.

Let me know if any of this was helpful.